# Change owner of files recursively, but not directories

Tags: permissions, chown

I have a directory that has ~50k directories and ~1m files.

I want to change owner (or permission) of all files, but not the directories. This is because i'm trying to SCP additional files from a remote server, (~150k directories and ~3.6m files).

The directory I have is a part of the remote directory, but the scp failed...

If i run SCP again, it will start over by overwriting the files i already copied from the remote directory.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `find`, it has an added advantage that the `ARG_MAX` will not be triggered in the process. From the parent directory:

```
find . -type f -exec chown newowner {} +
```

For `chmod`:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
```

`-type f` will `find` only files.

Comment: Works really great! Thanks! +1 for both chmod and chown

Comment: So `find` does not trigger `ARG_MAX`? I always thought it would have. You always learn something :)

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is to use `xargs`. You'll need to use the `-print0` option with `find` and a corresponding `-0` option of `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chown newuser:newgroup
```

From `man find`:

> **-print0**
>
> print the  full  file name on the standard output, followed by **a null character**. This **allows file names that contain newlines or other types of white space** to be correctly interpreted by programs  that  process  the  find output. This option corresponds to the -0 option of xargs.

`xargs` will also correctly handle `ARG_MAX`.

Comment: `find..exec` does handle weird file names..what makes you think it does not?

Comment: @heemayl I ran some tests and it seems you're right. I stand corrected. Thank you for pointing it out, I updated my answer.